# CSS Vertical Nav Menu Drop Down doesn't work in IE11

Tags: html, css

For some reason my CSS nav menu doesn't work in IE11. It works in Chrome or Firefox no problem. It's purely just CSS and no JavaScript used at all. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I have tried experimenting with doctypes but am not getting anywhere.

fffff
ffff
ffff
ffff

fff
fff

```css
nav ul {
 margin-top:1px; /* tucks the child ul up close to the parent li */
 border-color: blue;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 width: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
 list-style-type: none;
 border-color: aqua;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
}
nav ul li {
 display: none;
 border-color: lime;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 margin:1px;
 margin-top:-10px;
 margin-left:-10px;
}
nav {
 background-color: #c8b99c;  /* pale brown */
 width: 220px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
nav ul li.selected {
background-color: #c18946;
}
nav li a {  /* to make the whole box clickable, not just the link text */
 display:block; /* <<< this is the bit that does it */
 line-height:23px;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-color: red;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-style: solid;
}
nav li:focus-within ul li {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
 <title>My Webpage</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="nav_style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
   <li tabindex="1"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Home</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li tabindex="1"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Home</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>   
 </nav>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [focus-within](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within) is not supported by IE.

Comment: Ahh I see. Okay, so how do i edit this to work without focus-within? I tried using just :focus but this doesn't work for any browser at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `focus` you can achieve it like this:

```
nav li:focus ul li,
nav li a:focus + ul li{
    display: block;
}
```

[css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

> `div + p` selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements.

```css
nav ul {
 margin-top:1px; /* tucks the child ul up close to the parent li */
 border-color: blue;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 width: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
 list-style-type: none;
 border-color: aqua;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
}
nav ul li {
 display: none;
 border-color: lime;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 margin:1px;
 margin-top:-10px;
 margin-left:-10px;
}
nav {
 background-color: #c8b99c;  /* pale brown */
 width: 220px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
nav ul li.selected {
background-color: #c18946;
}
nav li a {  /* to make the whole box clickable, not just the link text */
 display:block; /* <<< this is the bit that does it */
 line-height:23px;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-color: red;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-style: solid;
}
nav li:focus ul li,
nav li a:focus + ul li{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
 <title>My Webpage</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="nav_style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
   <li tabindex="1"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Home</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li tabindex="1"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Home</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>   
 </nav>       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution

You can also implement this design using `nav li a:focus ~ ul li`.

Hope it may be help.

```css
  nav ul {
  margin-top:1px; /* tucks the child ul up close to the parent li */
  border-color: blue;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-color: aqua;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}
nav ul li {
  display: none;
  border-color: lime;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin:1px;
  margin-top:-10px;
  margin-left:-10px;
}
nav {
  background-color: #c8b99c;  /* pale brown */
  width: 220px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
nav ul li.selected {
background-color: #c18946;
}
nav li a {  /* to make the whole box clickable, not just the link text */
  display:block; /* <<< this is the bit that does it */
  line-height:23px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
nav li:focus ul li,
nav li a:focus ~ ul li{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Webpage</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="nav_style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
      <li tabindex="1"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Home</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li tabindex="1"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Home</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>     
  </nav>              
</body>
</html>
```